# ParseFacebookUtils login issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I'm building an app using `Parse` `SDK` and `Facebook SDK`. I'm using `ParseFacebookUtils` to log into the user's account with a token that is accessed like so:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    // User is not logged in
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];
} else
{
    // Have token, log in with it
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user)
        {
            // Error logging in
            NSLog(@"error");
        } else
        {
            // Logged in
            NSLog(@"success!");
        }
    }];
}
}
```

This works, and the user is signed in. This happens automatically (first app launch uses `logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:` instead).

However, when I log the user out using

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

The user is logged out (it appears like), but the token is retrieved during the next app launch, despite logging out - hence authenticating the user again.

I've tried to manually set the `currentAccessToken` like this - after calling `logOut`, but with the same result:

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
```

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 0):

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

Comment: I'm using version 4 of the SDK so unfortunately I do not have `FBSession`

Comment: OK, you can set token to nil 
`[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];`

Comment: I did, check out bottom of my post - it is set to nil but "restored" on the next app launch

Comment: Not exactly like that - there's no Facebook window that opens as I attempt to authenticate automatically using the token. Problem is that the token persists on the next launch despite clearing it on the previous launch

Comment: Did you try to logOut current PFUser ?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, so you think it will work? - any idea on why if so?